# How to declare a numpy matrix np.zeros with user defined dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose i want to declare a matrix which looks like this:

```
A=20
B=30
C=40

matrix = np.zeros(shape=(A,B,C),dtype=float)
```

Now i need to fill this matrix using successive for loops nested in each other:

*

```
for i in range(0,A):
  for j in range(0,B):
     for k in range(0,C):
        matrix[i][j][k] = ....
```

*

I want to implement the same code for n variables, where n is unknown till runtime. How could i solve this issue?

Comment: Depending on what you want to fill the matrix with, this can be made a lot easer & faster. What are the fill values?

Comment: The fill values are basically columns of an excel file. The A, B, C are no. of elements in each column.

Comment: Each column of the excel file will have the same size right?  The file is 2d, so why are you trying to fill and array that n-d?  How have you loaded this file? (another numpy array, list of lists or pandas)?

Comment: I'm trying to fill the matrix n-d so that i can compare all the variable values at once using an n dimensional graph. I loaded the file using pandas and yes each column should have the same size, i only mentioned A,B and C with different values to get a generalised answer (in case that is possible)

Comment: If you already have the data in a pandas dataframe, why would you want to copy the data into an array for comparison? Wouldn't it be easier to do that with the dataframe?

Comment: sorry for not explaining properly, was trying to find a general approach to it.

the thing is that my variables A,B,C are actually lists containing 4 elements, out of which one element is another list. I'm trying to take this list member from all of my variables and store it seperately into my new matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't think this is an good idea in an open ended case, here's a general approach, where the initial shape is all that I have to specify.

```
In [188]: ashape = (2,3,4)                                                                             
In [189]: arr = np.zeros(ashape)                                                                       
In [190]: arr.shape                                                                                    
Out[190]: (2, 3, 4)
```

`ndindex` is one of several tools to generate all combinations of indices:

```
In [191]: list(np.ndindex(ashape))                                                                     
Out[191]: 
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 2),
 (0, 0, 3),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 ....
 (1, 2, 3)]
```

Applied to setting values of `arr`:

```
In [192]: for idx in np.ndindex(ashape): 
     ...:     arr[idx] = np.sum(idx) 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [193]: arr                                                                                          
Out[193]: 
array([[[0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [1., 2., 3., 4.],
        [2., 3., 4., 5.]],

       [[1., 2., 3., 4.],
        [2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [3., 4., 5., 6.]]])
```

I could generate that array in other ways, for example

```
In [198]: np.indices((2,3,4)).sum(axis=0)                                                              
Out[198]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4, 5]],

       [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4, 5],
        [3, 4, 5, 6]]])
In [199]: idx = np.indices((2,3,4), sparse=True)                                                       
In [200]: idx                                                                                          
Out[200]: 
(array([[[0]],

        [[1]]]), array([[[0],
         [1],
         [2]]]), array([[[0, 1, 2, 3]]]))
In [201]: sum(idx)                                                                                     
Out[201]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4, 5]],

       [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4, 5],
        [3, 4, 5, 6]]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Is there any way to implement the same if I'm running my code with a GUI where the user can decide to omit certain variables and expects the matrix to resize itself accordingly ?